# Which are C# native built-in design patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Which design patterns are build-in supported by C# regardless framework version?
I'm thinking of patterns such as Observer pattern that can be found in interface IObservable. ObservableCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged etc.

Please provide with the namespace of the pattern in your answers!

Comment: For quite a long time I was thinking that extension methods implement the decorator pattern, but they don't: Decorator overrides and extends existing methods transparently whilst extension methods add new methods to an existing class. Still I'd be interested in whether there is a design pattern for that!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Action<T>` (normally used as visitor pattern)

**[Discover the Design Patterns You're Already Using in the .NET Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814171359/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx)** (`MSDN Magazine`)

**Example**

```
public class Root
{
    //Private and not exposed in a IList property = Encapsulation
    private List<Node> _nodes = new List<Node>(); 

    public void Accept(Action<Node> visitor)
    {
        // Controlled enumeration, can for instance handle exceptions in here.
        foreach (var item in _nodes)
        {
            visitor(node);
        }
    }
}

// usage
root.Accept(node => Console.WriteLine(node));
```

Comment: The link is now broken, but it's in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20120814171359/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx - OP, could you please update the post?

Comment: @jmdon: Done. thanks. Added a small example as a bonus.

Comment: Shouldn't the method be called `Accept()` as is tradition?

Answer (score 11):

**Creational Patterns**

Abstract Factory

- System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory

Builder

- System.Text.StringBuilder
- System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder

Factory Method

- System.Activator
- System.Net.WebRequest

Prototype

- System.ICloneable

Singleton

- System.StringComparer.InvariantCulture
- System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

**Structural Patterns**

Adapter

- System.IO.StreamReader

Bridge

- System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Composite

- System.ComponentModel.IComponent

Decorator

- System.IO.Stream

Facade

- System.Environment
- System.String

Flyweight

- System.StringComparer

Proxy

- System.Net.WebClient
- System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy
- System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject

**Behavioral Patterns**

Chain Of Responsibility

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger

Command

- System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs

Interpreter

- System.IFormatProvider
- System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Iterator

- System.Collections.IEnumerable
- System.Data.IDataReader

Mediator

- System.Threading.Timer

Memento

- System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable

Observer

- System.EventHandler
- System.IObservable

State

- ??

Strategy

- System.Collections.Generic.IComparer

Template Method

- System.Web.UI.Page

Visitor

- System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor

Comment: The inclusion of `ICloneable` above is incorrect. A prototype is expected to provide a deep, not shallow, copy of an object.

Answer (score 6):

Iterator is one (all collection classes and arrays can use the `foreach` statement for iteration).

Another is the observer pattern - pretty much this is what events are. In 4.0 the IObservable and ObservableCollection were added.

Answer (score 5):

Observer pattern. All our events and delegates are raised through the observer pattern.

Factory pattern. Connection strings and db providers from factory.

Iterator Pattern:  Ienumerable, Ienumerators in our foreach statements

Adapter: COM communication. Runtime Callable Wrappers(RCW)

Template: Used in several places esp in ASP.NET classes where you can override to provide new implementation

Proxy: For all our webservice calls. in c# 3.0 we got proxy collections as well.

There could be many more. But these are the ones that came to my mind

Answer (score 4):

[StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) uses the builder design pattern..
And there is the [DbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx) class (adapter pattern).
The [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is broadly used as well.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract Factory: [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The delegation pattern (that's what the delegates and expresssions are for)

Answer (score 0):

The proxy pattern is used often.